# Volley cannot create cache directory. Could not clean up file

Tags: android, android-volley

Below are the volley logs I am seeing. It says unable to create cache directory, and something about not being able to clean up a file.  What is the possible cause or resolution of this?

08-12 15:14:43.150: E/Volley(3868): [11] DiskBasedCache.initialize: Unable to create cache dir /volley
    08-12 15:14:45.732: D/Volley(3868): [15] DiskBasedCache.put: Could not clean up file /volley/12341768-824258

Answer (score 7):

Did you add the `android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` and `android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` to your manifest?

Comment: the app has WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with `Could not clean up file`. I resolved it by using Volley's `NetworkImageView` instead of an `ImageView`.